# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') whole component code is not working

Tags: html, reactjs

When I start the npm code for the cart component is not working and displayed the blank page
map function did not work. When I comment the part which is not working then another component like the header is displayed

```
import React  from 'react';
import Header from './Front/Header/Header';

    const Cart = (props ) => {
      const {cartitems} =props;
       const{handleAddProduct}=props;
       const {handleRemoveProduct}=props;
      return (
        <>
           <Header/>
            <div className="cart-items">
              <div className="cart-items-header"> cartitems</div>
              {!cartitems?.length ? (
                <div className="cart-items-empty"> No items added in cart</div>
              ) : null}
              <div>
           //this part of code is not working
                {cartitems.map((item) => (
                  
                <div key={item.id}>
               
               <div>
                 <img className="cart-items-image"
                    src={item.image}
                    alt={item.name}  />
                    </div>
                
              
               
                   <button className='cart-items-add' onClick={()=>handleAddProduct(item)}>+</button>
                   <button className='cart-items-remove' onClick={()=>handleRemoveProduct(item)}>-</button>
             
                    <div className='cart-items-price'>{item.quantity}* ${item.price}</div>
              
              </div>
                ))}
                </div>
               </div> 
                
          </>
      );
    }
    
    export default Cart;
```

here is the code of app.js in this code I got an error that cartitems.find is not a function plz let me know how to fix this issue

```
const { productitems } = data;
  const [cartitems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const History = useHistory();

  const handleAddProduct = (product) => {
    //  console.log(product);
     const ProductExist = cartitems.find((item) => item.id === product.id)
    // console.log(ProductExist);
    //  setCartItems(ProductExist);

    if (ProductExist) {
      setCartItems(
         cartitems.map((item )=> item.id ===product.id ? 
        {...ProductExist ,quantity:ProductExist.quantity +1}:item)
      )
     
    }
    else {
      setCartItems([...cartitems,{...product,quantity:1}])
      console.log('ni gya');
    }


  }
  const handleRemoveProduct = (product) => {
    const ProductExist = cartitems.find((item) => item.id === product.id);
    if (ProductExist.quantity === 1) {
      setCartItems(cartitems.filter((item) => item.id !== product.id));
    }
    else {
      setCartItems(
        cartitems.map((item) => item.id === product.id ?
          { ...ProductExist, quantity: ProductExist.quantity - 1 }
          : item)
      );

    }

  }
```

Comment: log `cartitems` and see if it returns an array. The error happens when you try to `map` through a non-array object.

Comment: At some point caritems is null or undefined, you need to protect your code against such scenarios, the easy way, just use `caritems && cartitems.map...`

Comment: after using cartitems && cartitems.map header componet is displayed but still remaining code is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can see there is a check above the code you commented out:

```js
{
  !cartitems?.length ? ( 
    <div className="cart-items-empty">No items added in cart</div>
  ) : null
}
```

It checks to make sure `cartitems` is an array before attempting to use `map()` on it. In the ternary statement, instead of returning `null` if `cartitems` is empty, you should return the map function so it would read:

```js
{!cartitems?.length ? (
  <div className="cart-items-empty"> No items added in cart</div>
) : cartitems.map(item => (
  // template code...
))}
```